# Need admin access to my Facebook app

Tags: admin, user-permissions

The developer who wrote my app initially is the only person who has admin rights to the app. Now it's being worked on by other developers and I cannot get him to grant me admin access. I've looked for ways around this but have not found a way yet, any help from the community would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would think this would be a good starting point: http://developers.facebook.com/support/. Who owns the app? If you own it and he was paid to create it for you, then sue him. He's got your property.

Comment: I own the app. The developer is in India. Checking your link now... I went though there pretty throughly but I'll def go though it again. Thank you.

Comment: As a general rule, don't pay contract developers until you have in your possession everything you're owed.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I figured out that it takes about 5 min to just get a new ID and recode my app. I haven't done it yet but it should be a breeze. One thing I'm worried about however, my app asked for users to verify who they were much more in the early stages and I hope a new ID doesn't resent the trust factor.